# Why m4 uses two different characters for quotes?

Tags: linux, m4

In virtually every language quoting strings is straightforward - you put some stuff before a string and then the same stuff at the end of a string (maybe mirrored), for example:

```
"string"
'string'
R"(string)"
```

m4 macro processor is different though, because strings are quoted using backtick and single quote like this:

```
`string'
```

My question is: does this approach have any technical justification or is it just an expression of authors creativity?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quoting [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M4_(computer_language)), it is related to controlling macro expansion in strings:

> Unlike most languages, strings in m4 are quoted using the backtick (`)
>   as the starting delimiter, and apostrophe (') as the ending delimiter.
>   **The use of separate starting and ending delimiters allows for the
>   arbitrary nesting of quotation marks in strings, allowing a fine
>   degree of control of how and when macro expansion takes place in
>   different parts of a string.**

Comment: It's the straight quotes that are the odd ones out. Almost every single natural language uses [mirrored quotes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotation_mark#Summary_table) for the same reason as m4. Straight quotes were only invented in the 1800s to save keys on typewriters, and it carried over to computers where ASCII was similarly cramped.